# PHP - Why can I not receive emails?

Tags: php

I created a form for my website visitors, I'm using PHP.

I don't know why, but I can't receive any emails when I submit the form.

This script just worked 2 times... what's wrong with my code?

Here, my HTML code:

```
 <form method="POST" action="empresa.php">
                  <a class="formtxt"> Name </a>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="name" class="txtbox" />
                  <br>
                  <a class="formtxt"> Company </a>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="company" class="txtbox" />
                  <br>
                  <a class="formtxt"> E-mail </a>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="email" class="txtbox" />
                  <br>
                  <a class="formtxt"> Telephone </a>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="telefone" class="txtbox" />
                  <br>
                   <a class="formtxt"> Subject</a>
                  <br>
                  <input type="text" name="subject" class="txtbox" />
                  <br>
                  <a class="formtxt"> Message </a>
                  <br>
                  <textarea class="txtarea" name="message"></textarea>
                  <br><br>
                  <input class="ctenviar" value="Enviar" type="submit">
               </form>
```

My PHP code:

```
<?php

$name = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['name']);
$telephone = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['telephone']);
$email = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['email']);
$subject = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['subject']);
$message = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['message']);
$company = mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['company']);

 mail("*****@gmail.com","$subject","
 name: $name
 Email: $email
 name: $telephone
 name: $company
 Email: $email
 subject: $subject
 message: $message","FROM:$name<$email>");


 echo "Thank You!"; 

 ?>
```

Comment: Why are you using `mysql_real_escape_string()`?

Comment: Using and **abusing** headers like that, is just asking for trouble. [`Read up on the subject`](http://php.net/mail) and [`header()`](http://php.net/header)

Comment: Look into your spam folder, then look to do some research, then use PHPMailer or SwiftMailer.

Comment: are you using localhost to send mail ? if yes check spam folder

Comment: "message:"? "name:" three times?

Comment: You cannot call `mysql_real_escape_string()` without prior establishment of a DB connection (except for the case where `mysql_connect()` succeeds with no passed parameters). See the [documentation](http://php.net/manual/function.mysql-real-escape-string.php).

Comment: Search `mysql_real_escape_string($_POST` and replace `$_POST` then search `']);` and replace `'];` in your favorite editor, will do the job in 0.03 seconds flat. Gawd, I should have posted this as an "answer" (grin)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not get any error message, then it's likely that the email is actually sent, but in your spam, or rejected. Be sure that the "From: " header is valid (valid mail address) and check your spam!

Answer (score 0):

1. You don't have a POST variable named `$_POST['telephone']`

   Your variable should be

   ```
   $_POST['telefone']
   ```
2. Make sure you are not working from local environement, as
   `mail()` will most likely fail there.
3. I agree with all the comments about my `mysqi_real_escape_string`

Hope this helps!